# Is it okay for an electrical switch to get warm?

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, dimmer-switch, multiway-switch

I installed a *FEIT Electric* dimmer switch on a circuit that controls 2 overhead lights.

I noticed that, even when not using the dimmer, the toggle portion of the switch is warm to the touch.  Is this okay?

This is the switch:

[image: FEIT Electric Dimmer Switch]

Here are a few more details:

- The circuit includes 2 switches.  The other switch is a standard non-dimmer switch.
- The 2 overhead lights each house 3 60W bulbs, for a total of 3*60*2=360W
- I think the bulbs in the light fixtures are halogen bulbs
- All electric wiring and circuit breakers are less than 15 years old

Comment: How warm, and what size wire is used in the circuit?

Comment: For cheap dimmers, there is no hard/switched "all the way on" position, they are dimming even at max light.  There should be a hard/switched "all the way off" position, but it may require use of the switch, not the slider.   The dimmer should not make any heat at all in a hard on/off position.

Comment: tl;dr: It's UL listed so as long as you bought from a reputable source, and installed it correctly, it's fine. It's up to the quality-of-implementation for wasting less energy as heat.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer, most dimmers do get warm when in use. If the dimmer does not have a mechanical method of turning completely off. Then there is a good chance that you are still getting some electrical flow through the switch and that would mean the dimmer could stay warm. In other words what @Harper said.

The biggest question I would have would be if it was getting excessively hot? I would say somewhere above 30 C (86 F) would seem to be excessive.

Comment: How hot is a good question, and I wish I had a way to provide you with an accurate answer.  It's warm to the touch even in a 26 C (79 F) environment, but definitely not hot to the touch.  I could hold a finger on it for hours without any temperature discomfort.

Comment: I should add that I incorrectly installed the switch at first, but fixed it after about 3 minutes of realizing my error.  If that new information changes your answer, please let me know.